# How to stop an action in cocos2d?

Tags: python, cocos2d-iphone

I have some experience working with Cocos2-x, but now I'm trying to develop a prototype using the original cocos2d in Python, and I found it pretty different. The thing is that I have a sprite on a layer

```
class TestLayer(cocos.layer.Layer):
    is_event_handler = True

    def __init__(self):
        super(TestLayer, self).__init__()
        self.sprite = cocos.sprite.Sprite('grossini.png')
        self.sprite.position = 320, 340
        self.add(sprite)
```

And I can move it:

```
def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
    if symbol ==key.RIGHT:
    move = MoveBy((1, 0), 0.1)
    repeat = Repeat(move)
    self.sprite.do(repeat)
```

But I don't know how to stop it on the `on_key_release` method. (In Cocos2d-x I could do `this->sprite->stopAction(action)`.

Also I want to know if there is a better way (the cocos2d Python way) to move and stop a sprite through user input.

I already read the documentation and some games samples, but I'm pretty n00b programming on Python, so I cant figure out this for myself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used cocos2d for python(only cocos2d-iphone) so I can't answer your question on if there's a better way to do this in general. But there are two ways to do what you're asking depending on your particular situation.

If you simply want to remove *all* actions on the sprite in `on_key_release()` all you need to do is call `stop()` on the sprite object which will remove all actions. So if your only action is the moving animation this should be enough.

def on_key_release(self, symbol, modifiers):
       if symbol == key.RIGHT:
           self.sprite.stop()

If, however, you only want to stop that specific action on the sprite and you want to keep other actions running. Then you need to save the action somewhere and then call `stop()` on the action and not the sprite. An example could be this:

```
def __init__(self):
    super(TestLayer, self).__init__()
    self.sprite = cocos.sprite.Sprite('grossini.png')
    self.sprite.position = 320, 340
    self.add(sprite)
    self.sprite_move_action = None

def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
    if symbol ==key.RIGHT:
        move = MoveBy((1, 0), 0.1)
        repeat = Repeat(move)
        self.sprite_move_action = repeat
        self.sprite.do(repeat)

def on_key_release(self, symbol, modifiers):
    if symbol == key.RIGHT and self.sprite_move_action is not None:
        self.sprite.remove_action(self.sprite_move_action)
        self.sprite_move_action = None
```

Comment: Thanks. I confirmed that `.stop()` stops all actions, but to stop just one, `.remove_action(action)` should be used: `self.sprite.remove_action(self.sprite_move_action)`.

Comment: Cool, I'll update my answer to reflect that so it's useful to whoever may happen upon it. I'm glad this helped as I don't have experience with cocos2d for python